# How debug TCP connections nodejs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, debugging, tcp

My app makes lots of http requests to another server(target server) and there is one of them that is not closing and is always on ESTABLISHED state causing many connections on the target server and eventually being blocked by csf because of many connections oppened.

I know the port of this connection using:

```
netstat -tapc
```

Is there a way to get which port http.request is using? Or another way to debug this would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found that is possible to retrieve the socket info used by http.request using:

```
response.socket
```

And to get the address/port used, just need to:

```
response.socket.address()
```

The code above returns a object with the port, ip and family of the ip used.

More about response.socket: [Node Socket API](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_address)